# java: Easiest way to gzip all my webapp content with Jetty?

Tags: java, jetty

I have some large pages and javascript files being downloaded from a web app using Jetty. What is the easiest way to GZIP all my content. I am hoping for something where I just add some lines to web.xml and add a jar file to WEB-INF/lib

Comment: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/GZIP+Compression

Comment: You want your users to be able to download everything as a gzip?

Comment: I want as much as possible to be gzipped. I realise that images are already compressed so there is not much saving there

Comment: I can't use the Jetty DefaultServlet as I have a custom servlet.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have your Jetty running behind a Apache Server via mod proxy you can use mod_deflate and then you have nothing to change at your web app at all.

See:
[Jetty/Tutorial/Apache](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Apache) and
[mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html)

Comment: Its just a plain Jetty server with no apache but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can use GzipFilter filter.
I doing it like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
        <param-value>application/javascript,application/x-javascript</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```